# Access part of ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How to access individual data in a python ndarray.

Data source is a .csv file from XL with two colums of data. Column 1 is an int (u-seconds) and column two is a string.

I have managed to read the file into an array:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("tim_stamp+val.csv", dtype=[('time','i8'),
('write','S5')], delimiter=",")
```

and it prints as:

```
array([(   272865, b'AA'), (   272899, b''), (   272895, b'55'), ...,
   (144297907, b'8'), (144297911, b''), (144297912, b'')],
  dtype=[('time', '<i8'), ('write', 'S5')])
```

data.shape ->
(3897,)

data[(4)] ->
(272934, b'5')

Can I adress/access the 'time' part in data[4], e.g 272934 "only" somehow? Say if I  would like to sum all 3897 instances of "time"...

Answer (score 0):

Changed the genfromtext to:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("tim_stamp+val.csv", delimiter=",")
```

which now produces:

```
array([[2.72865000e+05,            nan],
       [2.72899000e+05,            nan],
       [2.72895000e+05, 5.50000000e+01],
       ...,
       [1.44297907e+08, 8.00000000e+00],
       [1.44297911e+08,            nan],
       [1.44297912e+08,            nan]])
```

Accessing individual data:

```
data[2][1]
```

returns:

```
55.0
```

Problem solved. Hope it can help other noobies ;)

Need to change that float (55.0) to a string but thats next adventure ;)